# Link Aggression

Tags: router

Can I do Link Aggression on a CISCO RV 134 W Router to my Synology 716+ II NAS? I tried to figure out in router details, however I could not locate any 802.3ad protocol in the router. I am novice to networking and request if someone could advise. Do I need to purchase a managed switch with LAG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean link *aggregation*, not link *aggression*.

The IEEE 802 protocols are for LANs (layer-2). You aggregate interfaces on the same device that are on the same LAN. Routers route (layer-3) between LANs, so different router interfaces are on different LANs. On the other hand, switch interfaces are in the same LAN (absent something like VLAN configurations), so you can aggregate switch interfaces if the other end of the links are on the same device.

I'm not sure why you would need to aggregate in this case. You WAN connection is probably be much slower than even a single LAN link, and your router cannot even route at wire speed. I don't think you will gain anything by link aggregation to the router.

Comment: Yes it is aggregation and regret I misspelled. U r rite the WAN is very slow and to upload large file LAG sud assist.Will try and see how it works.